# Gimp record actions

Tags: automation, macros, gimp

I would like to execute some actions in Gimp and then apply this actions again to a new version of the file.

Is it possible ?

Edit: I would like to crop (and center the rest), resize. Maybe change background too.

Comment: [This page](http://gimp.open-source-solution.org/manual/gimp-scripting.html) could be helpful.

Comment: What kind of actions are you talking about? Simple resizing or color swap, or is it drawing shapes and things like that?Please give an example.

Answer (score 6):

There are two things you could try. The first is [GIMP scripting](http://gimp.open-source-solution.org/manual/gimp-scripting.html) or [GIMP BATCH](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/). These are ways of running GIMP in BATCH mode and scripting actions to be performed on a set of images.

The second way, which is much easier and, in your case, probably sufficient is the *wonderful* [ImageMagick suite](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). You can probably do everything you want using the `convert` tool of that suite. The following are some relevant options, you can see the whole list using `man convert` or by visiting [this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php).

```
NAME
      convert - convert between image formats as well as resize an image, blur, 
      crop, despeckle, dither, draw on, flip, join, re-sample, and much more.

SYNOPSIS
       convert [input-option] input-file [output-option] output-file

-background color    background color
-crop geometry       cut out a rectangular region of the image
-trim                trim image edges
-size geometry       width and height of image
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do one batch that command for all files in a dir? I got it to work for one file: convert `Screenshot_20200628_105148.png` -crop 1360x1080+0+0 output.png

Comment: Got it like this: `for file in *.png; do convert -crop 1360x1080+0+0 $file cropped_$file; done`

Comment: @torsten exactly! Just one improvement: use `"$file"` because otherwise, it will fail on any file names with spaces.